# Agile testing / traditional testing methods

Tags: agile

What are the agile testing methods? And what are the traditional testing methods?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Can you provide a hint as to the context in which you saw this?  Perhaps a link or a magazine article?  The distinction is artificial and it would help to know the context in which you saw these words.

Comment: Software development - it's just a question.

Comment: Traditional - when you are not doing it. Agile - when you are not doing it quickly.

Comment: I figured traditional testing is black/white/grey box testing...

Comment: Ok - well, in that case I'd suggest you read the link for Bret Pettichord's definition of testing schools (pretty short), and then rephrase your question accordingly.  There's nothing about black/white/grey box testing that says that it belongs solely to one school of testing or another.

Answer (score 5):

> What are the agile testing methods? And what are the traditional testing methods?

There are no "Agile Testing Methods" by itself as such but only testing done in an Agile Environment. Even if they exist, you cannot use "Agile Testing Methods" successfully in a waterfall organisation - so you have your concepts a little wrong there.

Anyway to give you some constructive feedback, the testing functions may very well be the same like waterfall, but the following may be different in an Agile Environment:

1. atmosphere and culture would be more collaborative (more face to face interaction),
2. tester involvement would be early,
3. the Team would code to a test, rather than code first and then create a test plan,
4. you would be cross functional so you may have to write code or do requirements gathering, and you will work closely with the customer,
5. you would work in 2 - 4 week iterations,
6. you would continually improve your testing procedures
7. you will not have a QA/Testing department
8. your role will be a "Team member who has most Testing experience" rather than "Tester"

Traditional methods are mostly the exact opposites of the check list above, seriously.

Answer (score 3):

In traditional testing, assuming [waterfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) process, testing happens after the development phase. Testers create their tests from the requirements gathered at the beginning of the project. In the stereotypical sense, large organizations have a QA department completely separated from development departments where they are handed the final application and documentation to write test cases from.

In an [agile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) environment testing occur asynchronously with development so that when a developer finishes a task it is tested so that at the end of the iteration the stakeholders know the task is a fully functional and tested. If bugs are revealed, they can be fixed earlier in the cycle, not in the final stretch.

This does not assume that every team writes using [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) or even [pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming)/[extreme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) programming.

One of the goals of agile is to improve communication between team members. Testers are included in the iteration planning and review meetings giving them more insight into what a given task is to accomplish. This will help them write tests beyond the sometimes vague black and white requirements.

I disagree with the notion that agile does not scale to larger projects that incorporate a QA department. Yes, in many cases and in some author recommendations agile teams are made of less than 10 but testing is integral in delivering a quality project. The challenge is how to proceed when corporate walls limit progress. How can I get a tester in my meetings or on my team? How can we get the QA more involved so that the customers are happy? etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am not shure if there are any "testmethods" that are special to agile.

Of course there is "testdriven" (tdd) and "behaviordriven" (bdd) development but i donot see these as "testing methods".

Unittests are not special to agile or traditional.

As @khachik mentioned it: there is offen a huge difference when (in the develpment process) the tests are desigend and applied.

Traditional = Waterfall or V-Modell: Test are done in the end (if at all)

Agile : Test should be written before the code is written.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if I rephrase it as "How do testing methods differ in Agile environments versus waterfall type environments" you may get answers along the lines of:

- In an Agile environment testing is, at a minimum, done at regular iterations (sprints).  In waterfall style environments, testing tends to be performed after development is complete.
- In an Agile environment testing is often included within development in the form of [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (TDD).  In a waterfall environment, testing is a separate stage of implementation.

In practice, this is a deep topic with complex perceptions on how development and testing should be done.  TDD is an up front thinking process and in theory removes the need for end testers.  Some argue that people skilled in [Exploratory Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing) are still needed regardless of the number of defined acceptance criteria and test cases.

The challenge in your question and even my rephrasing is that [Software Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) isn't a simple thing that fits in one place nor has one shape.  As for how it is actually done or should be done, there are thousands of articles on the topic with many opinions.

Comment: Would you call TDD testing?  I tend to think of TDD as more design than testing per-se.

Comment: Anything that validates functionality can be called a test.  TDD puts testing as part of the design exercise for a variety of reasons beyond the scope of this comment space.  I tend to think tests have a variety of different flavors.  Go right tests also form the basis for great regression tests.  Simple boundary testings and many corner case tests rarely detect breakage.  Any case, automation is the key.  Keep test costs down so a lot can be performed keeping the resulting quality higher.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you look up [Bret Pettichord's](http://www.pettichord.com/) presentation on the different schools of software testing, as a start.  There aren't just two schools - agile vs traditional, but at least five.  It's a great summary that will give you a quick overview.

The link posted above for Agile Testing, by Lisa Crispin and Janet Gregory is good, but I'd also strongly recommend:

[Elizabeth Hendrickson](http://testobsessed.com/) - last year's Pask award winner. Agile tester.  Why haven't you clicked on that link yet?

Also worth reading: [the Context-driven Testing principles](http://www.context-driven-testing.com)

Answer (score 0):

In traditional methods first the entire development will takes place then testing will start,whatever bugs are occur are fixed by developers.

In agile methodology testing is a continuous process and it done concurrently with the development of  the software components.
For regression perspective this type of testing will work more efficiently.

Agile testing is a fast process as compare to the traditional techniques.

Answer (score 0):

(A practice that follows the principles of agile software development is called Agile Testing.)
In a lay man’s term, testing can be referred to as revealing a person's or an organization’s capabilities by putting them under strain; challenging. It can also be referred to as making a plan first, realizing the goals, estimating and planning all the procedures and the risks involved and then testing- whether one is proceeding towards the decided goal or not. In case not, then agile helps to change and formulate the plan and fix the hindrances in order to meet the goal finally. With agile testing it has become easy now to check the workings in between the procedure unlike the waterfall method. Agile is an iterative development methodology, where requirements evolve through collaboration between the customer and self-organizing teams and agile aligns development with customer needs.